# Polymer Component <google-map> full screen in <core-drawer-panel>

Tags: google-maps, components, polymer, web-component

I'm able to have full screen Google Maps, and full screen the Polymer Component  where alone in the HTML page, but i can't go  full screen when used inside a  and , i need to set the Heigth to some value eg. height:600px; , so How i can set the full map inside these elements ? Here is my code :

```
  <body fullbleed layout vertical unresolved>
    <core-drawer-panel responsiveWidth="1500px">
    <core-header-panel drawer mode="waterfall-medium"></core-header-panel>

    <core-header-panel main mode="seamed">
      <core-toolbar>
        <span>Simple - Map</span>
      </core-toolbar>

      <!-- THe content of the core-header-panel -->
      <div main>

      <google-map></google-map>

    </div> 
  </core-header-panel>
</core-drawer-panel>
```

If i use the tag  outside the  i can see the map fullscreen but not if inside ! Some Help !

Comment: https://divshot.com/blog/web-components/wrapping-google-maps-with-polymer-elements/ show how to set height value

Comment: This is not the answear i'm looking for .... my problem is not to set the google-map CSS property but understand how the parent  </core-header-panel> </core-drawer-panel> manage the hight .... because is the parent height that do not show my google-map full screen ....